# Display integer in a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I am trying to implement a calculator. There are two textfields for the numbers that are used to calculate the answer. Afterwards I have to display the result as an integer answer in a `UILabel`.

When I try this I get the following error:

```
error is incompatible type
```

Comment: Show us code, please!

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you aren't showing us how you are trying to set the text?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `xcode 4.2` just because you are using `xcode` doesn't mean you should use the `xcode` tag. The `xcdoe` tag is reserved for issues with the `xcode IDE` itself not issues you are having within it. Tag your question correctly will help get you the best possible answer. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @KapteinMarshall that looks nothing like Objective-C ;)

Comment: @dasdom I think we can *almost* assume that the OP did something like this: `myLabel.text = 1;`

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist It's more like an educational remark. Askers should know how to ask.

Comment: OP had his tags wrong... horribly wrong. What I posted is for C#. CultureInfo.InvariantCulture is just a very decent way to do so... Doing it in objective-c is somewhat different and looks more like this...myAnswerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Answer: %d", answerInteger];    My objective c is suuuper rusty

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would create a `NSNumberFormatter` and specify that is shouldn't have any fraction digits. This will give you the rounding behavior you are expecting.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0;

// will be "2" since 1.5 is rounded up  
NSString *numberText = [formatter stringFromNumber:@1.5];

// will be "1" since 1.25 is rounded down
NSString *anotherNumberText = [formatter stringFromNumber:@1.25];
```

This will be the best solution if you decide to support decimal numbers in the future. Then you can change the number of fractions to another number and have the appropriate rounding without getting extra trailing zeroes.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;

// will be "1.5" since no rounding is required (and no extra digits is required)    
NSString *numberText = [formatter stringFromNumber:@1.5];

// will be "1.13" since 1.125 is rounded up
NSString *anotherNumberText = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(1.0/8.0)]; // 1.125 

// will be "3.14" since 3.1415.. is rounded down
NSString *yetAnotherNumberText = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(M_PI)]; // 3.1415..
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a format specifier when setting the text.

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The number is %d", myInteger];
```

You can do this with floats with `%f`, characters with `%c`, objects with `%@`, etc.